# Strange behavior while creating an image and video array (videos loading first or not at all)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, video

I have a JSON feed (retrieved with `.ajax` long polling) with both movie and picture links.  I want to "preload" all the images and videos, by adding them to an array.

I want the media objects to be added to the array in the order they are in the feed.  I have a fairly straight forward script that loops through the feed but here is what I encounter:

When I write the code to add the items to the array if I specify videos first they all are loaded into the front of the array (ahead of any images in the feed are added, even though there are images ahead of any movies).

Here is my code:

```
//JSON Feed = http://app.sportstream.com/api/tagstream/tagStreamForStageTwoModeration?q=%7B%22customerId%22:%22ab.inch.2014%22,%22type%22:%7B%22$in%22:%5B%22image%22,%22video%22%5D%7D%7D&_=_ 

(It returns an array of entries)

for (var k = 0, j = entries.length; k < j; k++) {
    var limit = 0;
    if (idCheck.indexOf(entries[k].id) == -1) {
        if (++limit > 75) return;
        idCheck.push(entries[k].id);

        var mediaObject = new CustomMedia();

        //Placing this here will load all videos in feed to front of array

        if (entries[k].type == 'video') {
            mediaObject.isVideo = true; 
            mediaObject.url = entries[k]['ssMetaData']['videos']['standard_resolution']['url'];
            console.log('New VIDEO Loaded');
            contentArrayNew.push(mediaObject);
            if (!preLoadDone && boxCount != null) {
                if (contentArrayNew.length >= boxCount) {
                    preLoadDone = true;
                    imagesLoaded();
                }
            }
            //Checking if type == 'image' before video prevents any videos from loading
        } else if (entries[k].type = 'image') {
            mediaObject.isVideo = false;
            mediaObject.url = entries[k]['ssMetaData']['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];

            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = (function (entry) {
                return function () {
                    contentArrayNew.push(entry);
                    console.log('New IMAGE Loaded');
                    if (!preLoadDone && boxCount != null) {
                        if (contentArrayNew.length >= boxCount) {
                            preLoadDone = true;
                            imagesLoaded();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })(mediaObject);
            img.onerror = function () {
                console.log('error: bad image source');
            };
            img.src = mediaObject.url;

        }  else {
            console.log('Invalid media format');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `contentArrayNew.push(mediaObject)` immediately, instead of in the `onload` function?

Comment: I did not want to add any media to the to the array until it has been preloaded.

Comment: Then you need to put an empty element in the array as a placeholder. Then when the image is preloaded, replace the placeholder with the media object.